# WooCommerce Student Discount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, coupon, discount

I need to create a coupon in WooCommerce that will only work if the user has an email which ends in `.ac.uk`.

For example `student.name@uwl.ac.uk` or `teacher@kings.ac.uk`.

The discount would be 10% off the total shopping basket.

I can't find any solutions online or any plugins which could help.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this **Auto apply Discount Coupon to Customer’s Purchase function** with the right conditionals (user email finishing by `ac.uk`):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'coupon_auto_apply_user_email_tld', 10, 0);
function coupon_auto_apply_user_email_tld() {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_email = $current_user->user_email; 
    $mail_part = explode('@', $user_email);
    $domain_part = explode('.', $mailParts[1]);
    $mail_tld = $domain_part[1] . '.' . $domain_part[2];

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( $mail_tld == 'ac.uk' ) {
        $coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE'; // <= set the name of your coupon code here
        if ( ! WC()->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $coupon_code ) ) ) {
            WC()->show_messages();
        }
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_message"><strong>The total price in your cart will be discounted 10% off…</strong></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

You will have to set in WooCommerce coupon settings a coupon with the desire behavior (10% off) and you will report this coupon slug in this function.

Copy code in the functions.php file located in your active theme or better your active child theme.