# Coupons are automatically applied based on user_email

Tags: woocommerce, cart, checkout, coupon

- I searched for related documents but no longer works.([WooCommerce Student Discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686948/woocommerce-student-discount/37688331#37688331))
- I need to create a coupon in WooCommerce that will only work if the user has an email which ends in hcmute.edu.vn.
- For example 15104032@student.hcmute.edu.vn

  **Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/) you can go for `Usage Restriction` with the `Allowed Emails/Email restrictions` option, using wildcard character to mact multiple email addresses from a same domain.

> Allowed Emails/Email restrictions – Email address or addresses that
>   can use a coupon. Verified against customer’s billing email.
>   **WooCommerce 3.4+ also allows you to include a wildcard character (*)
>   to match multiple email addresses, for example, `*@gmail.com`** would
>   make any gmail address.

Comment: not working with WooCommerce 3.4+? not working using the wildcard `*@student.hcmute.edu.vn`?

Comment: I am using WooCommerce 3.4.5 and using the wildcard *@student.hcmute.edu.vn. When using @gmail.com, coupon is still active

Comment: It should work, I have to make tests on my side for a better understanding of the issue.