# WooCommerce Student Discount issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I am trying to give a discount on Woocommerce on Wordpress if email is .ac.uk.

I found a solution on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686948/woocommerce-student-discount)

I tried to use above solution but it gave this error:

**syntax error, unexpected ')'**

On line:

**`$mail_tld = $domain_part[1] . '.' . $domain_part[2]);`**

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Thanks, functions now accepts it, however, throws an error on cart now.

Comment: Full error paste: https://pastebin.com/dYDCwmhn

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail_tld = ($domain_part[1] . '.' . $domain_part[2]);
```

add '(' in this line.